# SVG text overflow, rendered with ellipsis

Tags: svg, overflow

This is my SVG, drawn in draw.io.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hVWrAL8CysF9wlDvZa3D3XfXwNy4Y3iV/view?usp=sharing

A MWE, I use `inkscapelatex=false` to keep the font:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includesvg[scale=0.85,inkscapelatex=false]
        {./parser_sequence.svg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: overflow text]

How can I make the text rendered fully, without ellipsis?

Comment: The ellipsis is also in the source file - each string is represented two times, one time as full string and one time abbreviated. The second variant is displayed by `\includesvg`, and also by various other tools (Inkscape itself for example). Modify the source file (in a text editor) to get the full strings.

Comment: But it display nothing then... I think it's because of LaTeX/Inkscape doesn't have good support for foreign object (the ellipsis text is inside a `<switch>` element, and the other option of the switch is `foreignObject`).

Comment: Is it possible to instruct drawio to not shorten the label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original SVG contains the following lines:

```xml
<switch>
<foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
   <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe flex-end; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 696px; margin-left: 468px;">
      <div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; ">
         <div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 13px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; background-color: #ffffff; white-space: nowrap; ">
         InputStream as Text
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</foreignObject>
<text x="468" y="696" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="13px" text-anchor="middle">
InputStream a...
</text>
</switch>
```

The `svg` package (and Inkscape itself, which the package uses to do the conversion) does not use the `foreignObject` tag, and instead use the `text` object below it, which has the ellipsis. The package produces warnings about this in the terminal log:

```
WARNING: unknown type: svg:foreignObject
```

Note that some editors do not display this log so you might miss the warnings (they are not printed in the log file, only in the terminal).

To show the full string in your LaTeX document you can edit the source of the svg. Besides modifying the text it is also useful to change the `x` coordinate a bit to position the string better.

Modified code:

```xml
<text x="480" y="696" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="13px" text-anchor="middle">
InputStream as Text
</text>
```

Resulting pdf:

[image]

Note that using the same mechanism the SVG prints a warning message in the output about SVG support (shown in the screenshot). You can edit this out as well - or alternatively trim the resulting pdf, but editing the source seems easier.

Some background information from draw.io itself:
https://drawio.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/16000042487-why-text-in-exported-svg-images-may-not-display-correctly (emphasis mine)

> When you look at a diagram exported to an SVG image in IE or some SVG
> editors, the text may not display correctly.
>
> diagrams.net uses something called foreign objects in SVG to allow
> complex, HTML labels on shapes.
>
> We can account for this dynamically if you use diagrams.net in IE11 or
> earlier. However, the exported SVG will not show all labels when the
> SVG image file is viewed in IE and **most SVG editors (such as
> Inkscape and Illustrator)**, as well as some online services such as
> Wordpress. Instead, you will see an error [Not supported by viewer]
> instead, or a parse error if you are trying to view the SVG file in
> WordPress.
>
> We are aware of the problem and have spent a considerable amount of
> time researching solutions. However, the subject is very complex and
> we don’t have a fix so far. We will continue to investigate it.
>
> In the meantime, **consider exporting your diagram to a PDF file** as
> this is also a vector format, or disable formatted text and word
> wrapping for all labels in your diagram before you export it to SVG by
> following the steps below.
>
> 1. Right click on a blank area of the drawing canvas, then choose Select All from the context menu.
> 2. In the Text tab of the format panel, uncheck the Formatted Text option.
> 3. Right click on a blank area of the drawing canvas, then choose Select Vertices.
> 4. In the Text tab of the format panel, uncheck the Word Wrap option.
>
> Note: When you disable these formatting options, you can still style
> the label text as a whole. You can not apply different formatting to
> parts of the label.